# Is it OK to neglect repeated letters when buying a domain?

Tags: seo, domains

If my site’s name consists of two words and the first word ends with the same letter that the second word begins with, for example `paperreview.com`, is it ok to remove one of the `r`’s and just have `papereview.com`?

Would this domain be harder to reach?

Comment: I don't think theres a solid answer to this question because it really depends on the user. Some might find it creative to remove a repeating letter to access a domain while others leave it in to make the domain make more sense.

Comment: ...and depends on the domain name. The "new word" might be easy to say, easy to remember and _unique_. It just _depends_.

Comment: You would lose traffic on people who enter the address manually because a lot of people will spell the words correctly. Single words with double letters work better than double words because its easier to spot, double words it becomes hard... take a glance at `repairepeater.com` and then `repairrpeater.com` most people would not notice the incorrect spelling. A good example of double singular words is `fiverr.com` its easy to notice.

Comment: It may or may not be harder to reach, but having the same letter repeated definitely makes it harder to read.  Most people don't realise caps are OK in domain names - PaperReview.com is much easier to read than paperreview.com.

Comment: @Steve true, but sadly Search Engines and browsers do not display caps within the domain name.

Comment: @SimonHayter - oh, sorry I wasn't meaning to imply that.  It was just a point for people who think they are harder to read.

Comment: @Steve actually Yandex lets you choose capitalisation in their Webmaster Tools. I'd love to see Google & Bing start doing the same.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say you should never skip such letters unless that's the actual name of the website/company/product/etc.

Going by your example I would understand that papereview.com would be something like paper-e-view - something related to digital viewing of papers. Or Pape-review - a website that reviews Papes (whatever that might be). But you want it to be about reviewing papers so it probably could be misleading if you removed that "repeating" letter. Also this might bring more confusion to visitors as instead of writing two full words, they must explicitly remember that one letter must be removed. The same would be when you create a domain with extra letters like Arrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrg.com. So who will actually do the counting of those letters and remember it each time they want to visit the site?

What you could do is prevent such "repeats" (if the situation allows) like changing paperreview.com to something like ireviewpapers.com (depending on what your website is actually about).

Also, SEO might be actually in your favor if you use separate dictionary words instead of making some abomination. Blogging-platform.com would perform better than tumblr.com as it has a searchable phrase in it's domain name by default (though my SEO knowledge is rusty).

Answer (score 0):

Using whole terms in a domain name can be extremely powerful if done well even though domain name exact match search results rank lower and nearly last in the SERPs.

The reason is simple. Semantics. Terms used in a domain name are scored semantically and scored high giving topical weight to the site overall. If a site about cars has a domain name of abc.com (extreme example), then the domain name gives no semantic value to the site. Abc says nothing. But a domain name of allaboutcars.com (my apologies if this is a real domain name) gives strong semantic signals for the site topic. These signals are scored high. This of course does not work if the site does not support the topic cars or any other terms found within the domain name. Howtofixyourcar.com cannot be about baking bread for example, but rather must be about car repair. [Insert Duh(!) here.]

Breaking terms or abbreviating terms in a non-traditional way will defeat this effect. Information Technology is easily recognized as IT. This would work. However, InforTechn (obvious example) would not.

Answer (score 0):

There will be no ranking benefit or devaluation based on the domain.

But you need to think of the user here. I'm guessing your brand will still include the two Rs, so when a user types your name directly in to the browser they may get a DNS failure or another site thinking it has two Rs.

Also think about people that may want to link to you, it would easy to get the URL wrong.

So on that basis I think it's a bad idea -- Just my thoughts.

@WiliamHarvey

Answer (score 0):

If both domains are available, buy both domains and redirect the incorrectly spelled one to the correctly spelled one.

Answer (score -2):

So if I find a domain name for example  HouseContruction.com that would have 135,0000 click a month but is expensive about 19,0000 dollars.
 to bus and I find again HhouseContruction.com and gots 90,0000 click a month should I buy it...for 18 $ or not u see difference...

Comment: HhouseContruction.com is *not* going to get 90,000 clicks a month, though.